# Can I set the "open file location feature" to open in Total Commander?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, total-commander

I don't know what the official name is. But many programs have this feature. When used an explorer window opens with the the appropriate file(s) highlighted. I want it to be opened in TC.

There's a similar (but simpler feature), opening a folder. Which can be made to open in TC via this: https://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php?title=Explorer_integration

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add a command to your context menu to open any file in Total Commander. You can use a similar registry file as used in the link you mentioned, just replace `Folder` with `*` (asterisk). For example:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Total_Commander] 
@="Total Commander"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Total_Commander\command] 
@="\"C:\\Program files\\totalcmd\\TOTALCMD64.EXE\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: I actually wanted all folders to be opened in TC. But apparently it doesn't work all the time
The dev of Potplayer led me to believe that there's a difference between when an app just want to open a folder or wants to open a folder with files selected. (Either this or they're using different APIs)

With potplayer and utorrent I get the folder opened with the registry changes that I linked but the program becomes partially hung up and an explorer window is opened anyway after half a minute with the file in questing highlighted. (the parent is svchost.exe) Which supports the devs claims.